How to manage virtual environments with pyenv?
Scenario
I would like to start a new project in python. I need a different version of python than the one on my system (Ubuntu 23.10), so I followed the steps below:

I downloaded pyenv and installed the desired version of python;
I moved into the project folder
I created a virtual environment via pyenv
Now I have to install my dependencies into the venv

Before install any package, i checked the python version to make sure i'm using the correct version of python but the output confused me:
# Outside the project directory using `python`

    ubuntu:~/Outside_Project_Folder$ python --version
    pyenv: python: command not found

    The `python` command exists in these Python versions:
      3.12.3
      3.12.3/envs/.venv
      .venv

    Note: See `pyenv help global` for tips on allowing both
          python2 and python3 to be found.

    ubuntu:~/Outside_Project_Folder$ which python
    /home/usr/.pyenv/shims/python


# Outside the project directory using `python3`

    ubuntu:~/Outside_Project_Folder$ python3 --version
    Python 3.11.6

    ubuntu:~/Outside_Project_Folder$ which python
    /home/usr/.pyenv/shims/python3


# Inside the project directory using `python` or `python3`

    ubuntu:~/Project$ python --version
    Python 3.12.3

    ubuntu:~/Project$ which python 
    /home/usr/.pyenv/shims/python


Question
I am confused about how to install dependencies within the virtual environment associated with the version of python installed with pyenv.
I thought about running pip install from within the project folder but I'm afraid that doing so might pollute the version of python installed via pyenv.
I would like to install the packages exclusively for my project, but how do I understand if I am inside the virtual environment?
Also how do I figure out what is the current active version of phyton wherever I am in the file system?

You've not shown any virtualenv, but you'll need to activate one. Checkout instructions at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

you could just create a requirements.txt file and install that.
